# Using QueryXML with SUDS and Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, suds

I'm trying to use a QueryXML with SUDS to query Autotask. However I'm not able to use the QueryXML because of an indentation error. This is my code:

```
class ConnectATWS():
    def __init__(self):
        #Connect to server with the credentials
        app_config = Init()
        self.username = app_config.data["Username"]
        self.password = app_config.data["Password"]
        self.login_id = app_config.data["LoginID"]
        self.url = app_config.data["AutotaskUpdateTicketEstimatedHours_net_autotask_webservices5_ATWS"]
        strCurrentID = "0"
        strCriteria = "<condition><field>Status<expression op=""NotEqual"">5</expression></field></condition>"
        strQuery = "<queryxml><entity>Ticket</entity><query>" & _
                        "<condition><field>id<expression op=""greaterthan"">" & strCurrentID & "</expression></field></condition>" & strCriteria & _
                        "<condition><field>EstimatedHours<expression op=""isnull""></expression></field></condition>" & _
                        "</query></queryxml>"

        client = Client(self.url + "?WSDL", username=self.login_id, password=self.password)
        response = client.service.query(strQuery)
        print response
```

This is my error:

```
File "/Users/AAAA/Documents/Aptana/AutotaskUpdateTicketEstimatedHours/Main.py", line 35
    "<condition><field>id<expression op=""greaterthan"">" & strCurrentID & "</expression></field></condition>" & strCriteria & _
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

How can I bypass the indentation error and run the query?

Comment: Can you paste the entire stack trace of the error you're getting?  What are you trying to do with the "&" and "_" operators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't concatenate the strings with the & character, try + instead.  Also you need to use the "\" to handle those line breaks:

```
strQuery = "<queryxml><entity>Ticket</entity><query>" + \
                        "<condition><field>id<expression op=""greaterthan"">" + strCurrentID + "</expression></field></condition>" + strCriteria + \
                        "<condition><field>EstimatedHours<expression op=""isnull""></expression></field></condition>" + \
                        "</query></queryxml>"
```

Comment: Thanks, now i have to figure our how to properly use QueryXML with the AutotaskAPI with SUDS..